# Create Custome Object from two sources

Tags: c#, merge

What is the best way to create a custome object from 2 sources. I have source A & source b and from this two sources I want to create one new object.

Source A:

```
public class A
{
    public A(string lastName, string firstName, string street, string city)
    {
        LasetName = lastName;
        FirstName = firstName;
        Street = street;
        City = city;
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Source B:

```
public class B
{
    public B(string lastName, string firstName, string street, string city, int shoeSize)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
        FirstName = firstName;
        Street = street;
        City = city;
        ShoeSize = shoeSize;
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    
    public int ShoeSize { get; set; }
}
```

So the new object should take the LastName, FirstName, Street from source A and Street, City and ShoeSize from source B.

In real the sources are much bigger and I know I could do it like this:

```
var a = new A("dd", "afafd", "asdf","adf");
var b = new B("dd", "afafd", "asdf","adf",22);

var custome = new Custome(a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.Street, b.City, b.ShoeSize);
```

But is there a nicer way?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do and why. However, why not `public class C { public A A { get; set; } public B B{ get; set; } }` ?

Comment: Can be done via reflection and dynamic CIL generation. But that would be extremely complex and not what you want to store normally in code base. @Dario M.

Comment: Do you mean you want merge tow objects and the new object have an union of member variables？

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is not possible in C#, however it can be simulated using interfaces, see Simulated Multiple Inheritance Pattern for C#.

The basic idea is to define an interface for the members on class B that you wish to access (call it IB), and then have C inherit from A and implement IB by internally storing an instance of B, for example:

```
class C : A, IB
{
    private B _b = new B();

    // IB members
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _b.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

I hope I could help.